# why is the weight for guards in exit position equal to weight of both guard ans exit flagged nodes for exit position?

Tags: exit-relays, directory, bandwidth, guard, consensus

Why is the weight factor Weg set equal to Wed in tor code (in file dirvote.c)? How does it still result in correct probabilities?